# Change donation to another donor

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

We have accidentally attributed a credit card donation to the wrong person. How can we change the donation to the correct donor? Do we have to delete the donation on one record and add it to the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension called [Move Contribution](https://civicrm.org/extensions/move-contribution) that will allow you to move the contribution, however, it does not appear to have been updated since Aug. 2016 and last compatible version was 4.7, so there is a chance that the extension will not work with whatever version of Civi you are on.

In the absence of the above, and assuming that the correct credit card was charged but just recorded on the wrong contact, the correct way to manage this is to:

1. Navigate to the original contribution and click the Edit hyperlink
2. Change the Contribution Status to "Cancelled" (financial transactions should never be deleted, especially where electronic ones are concerned)
3. Since transaction IDs must be unique, make note of the transaction ID, then add a "-C" in the original contribution's transaction ID field
4. (OPTIONAL): If your version tracks the information, make note of the card type and last 4 digits of the card
5. Click the Save button
6. Navigate to the correct contact record's contribution tab and click Add Cash/Check... Contribution
7. Record the contribution details, selecting the payment method of credit card
8. Enter the original transaction ID you noted in item 3 above and any additional card details as desired
9. Click the Save button

If the incorrect credit card was charged, then you will need to issue a refund directly through the payment processor, change the original contribution status to "Refunded" in CiviCRM, and then process the correct credit card on the correct contact record accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Tamar

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange, Nadya. In case the extension recommended by Tamar does not work out, you could check out [this one called rebook](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.rebook) which we developed a while ago.

Unfortunately, it has not been tested with the current version either bit you may give it a try. As always when tying out something new, use a testing environment if possible.

Comment: Hey Fabian - sorry for overlooking your extension - it doesn't seem to be listed here: https://civicrm.org/extensions - would have mentioned it otherwise.

Comment: Hey Tamar, nor worries at all. Getting an extension in the directory can be a bit of a pain which is why we sometimes don't bother...